# Add arrays to my ExecuteReader() function

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to get the data from a database that I created in MYSQL. I believe the DML in my code is correct. I saw on another thread that I need to use arrays so I can get all the rows from my table, but I'm struggling on how to include them in my code:

```cs
string cs = "server...";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);


try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection sur MySQL...");
    connection.Open();
 
    string Insertion ="insert into Passager(...)values(...)";
    string Insert2 = "insert into Reservation(...)values(...)";
    string req1 = "SELECT CodePassager,";
    string req2 = "SELECT CodePassager,...";
    string req3 = "SELECT CodePassager,...";
    string joint = "SELECT Reservation...";

    MySqlCommand NQuery = new MySqlCommand(Insertion, connection);
    MySqlCommand NQuery2 = new MySqlCommand(Insert2, connection);
    MySqlCommand requete1 = new MySqlCommand(req1, connection);
    MySqlCommand requete2 = new MySqlCommand(req2, connection);
    MySqlCommand requete3 = new MySqlCommand(req3, connection);
    MySqlCommand reqjoint = new MySqlCommand(joint, connection);

    NQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
    NQuery2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //1st request
    using (MySqlDataReader reader1 = requete1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader1.Read();
        int CodePassager;
        string Nom, Prenom;
        CodePassager = (int)reader1[0];
        Nom = (string)reader1[1];
        Prenom = (string)reader1[2];
        Console.WriteLine("code: {0},nom:{1},prenom:{2}", CodePassager, Nom, Prenom);
        reader1.Close();
    }

    //2nd request
    using (MySqlDataReader reader2 = requete2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader2.Read();
        int CodePassager;
        string Nom, Prenom, Adresse;
        CodePassager = (int)reader2[0];
        Nom = (string)reader2[1];
        Prenom = (string)reader2[2];
        Adresse = (string)reader2[3];
        Console.WriteLine("code:{0},...);
        reader2.Close();
    }

    //3rd request
    using (MySqlDataReader reader3 = requete3.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader3.Read();
        int CodePassager;
        string Nom, Prenom, Adresse;
        CodePassager = (int)reader3[0];
        Nom = (string)reader3[1];
        Prenom = (string)reader3[2];
        Adresse = (string)reader3[3];
        Console.WriteLine("code: {0}...);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Reservation(s) pour ce client:");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");

        reader3.Close();
        //request to show every reservation per passenger
        using (MySqlDataReader reader4 = reqjoint.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader4.Read();
            int CodeReservation;
            string StatutReservation, DateReservation;
            CodeReservation = (int)reader4[0];
            StatutReservation = (string)reader4[1];
            DateReservation = (string)reader4[2];
            Console.WriteLine("code reservation:{0}...);
            reader4.Close();
        }
    }


}

catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
   
    connection.Close();
}
```

With my current code, I get only one result for each request, but I need all the data.

(Sorry, English is not my first language.)

Comment: Search how a MySqlDataAdapter works. It allows you to get a DataTable with all the data returned by your query. A DataTable is a glorified array.

Comment: ill definitely take a look thank you, but since this is a school project i should be using what i learned so far wish include arrays

Comment: I think the Examples section of [MySqlDataReader](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) is what you are looking for.

Comment: thx for the answer @DanielDearlove but i already took a look at it and it doesn't show how to get multiple outputs, i did the same thing as the exemple and i'm only getting one row from the table.

Comment: looking at the example section @DanielDearlove mentioned, i can see that the answer is hidden somewhere in there.
check for the word "while" in the code snippet there

Comment: by the way, the reason we are answering so cryptically is here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You need to loop the reader `while(reader.Read()) { ....` Side note: you should dispose your connection with `using`

Comment: thankx michael for the clarification i didnt know about the homework thing.

Comment: thank you to everyone who answered, i found my error, i hadn't fully understood the while() until you pointed it out and i got it fixed except for the last while which require me to have a while loop in an open reader and i only found [this](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter~_ctor(MySqlCommand).html) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-datareader-dataset-dataadapter-and-datatable-in-c-sharp1) and i'm not sure if i'm heading the right way

Comment: @FAD By the way, as you may have noticed from the syntax highlighting on SO, you are missing a few quotation marks in your code. Make sure to fix those in your own code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, the answer is in the Examples section of [MySqlDataReader](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) but the code is not very well written. A better version should make it clear how to read multiple values from a select query:

```
public void ReadMyData(string myConnString) {
    string mySelectQuery = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM Orders";

    using(MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnString))
    using(MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery,myConnection))
    {   
        myConnection.Open();

        using(MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Always call Read before accessing data.
            while (myReader.Read()) {
                Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + myReader.GetString(1));
            }

            // always call Close when done reading.
            myReader.Close();
        }

        // Close the connection when done with it.
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Many of the types are disposable so they can be used with a `using` section. Also, the [`MySqlConnection.Close`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_Close.htm) method indicates it is the preferred way to close a connection so it should be manually closed rather than depend on the disposal. I have assumed the same for `MySqlDataReader.Close` though the documentation does not say anything.

Answer (score 0):

thank you to everyone who answered, i found my error, i hadn't fully understood the while() until you pointed it out and i got it fixed except for the last while which require me to have a while loop in an open reader ( 3rd and 4th request) and i only found [this](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql%7EDevart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter%7E_ctor(MySqlCommand).html) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-datareader-dataset-dataadapter-and-datatable-in-c-sharp1) and i'm not sure if i'm heading the right way.
this is how i fixed my answer:

```
        //1st request
        using (MySqlDataReader reader1 = requete1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                int CodePassager;
                string Nom, Prenom;
                CodePassager = (int)reader1[0];
                Nom = (string)reader1[1];
                Prenom = (string)reader1[2];

                Console.WriteLine("code: {0}...");
            }
            reader1.Close();
        }

        //2nd request
        using (MySqlDataReader reader2 = requete2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                int CodePassager;
                string Nom, Prenom, Adresse;
                CodePassager = (int)reader2[0];
                Nom = (string)reader2[1];
                Prenom = (string)reader2[2];
                Adresse = (string)reader2[3];
                Console.WriteLine("code: {0}...");
            }
            reader2.Close();
        }

        //3rd request
        using (MySqlDataReader reader3 = requete3.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader3.Read())
            {
                int CodePassager;
                string Nom, Prenom, Adresse;
                CodePassager = (int)reader3[0];
                Nom = (string)reader3[1];
                Prenom = (string)reader3[2];
                Adresse = (string)reader3[3];
                Console.WriteLine("code: {0}...");
                reader3.Close();
                using (MySqlDataReader reader4 = reqjoint.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader4.Read())
                    {
                        int CodeReservation;
                        string StatutReservation, DateReservation;
                        CodeReservation = (int)reader4[0];
                        StatutReservation = (string)reader4[1];
                        DateReservation = (string)reader4[2];
                        Console.WriteLine("code...");
                    }
                    reader4.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

}